# How to use python to start an interactive shell program?

Tags: python, shell

I have used python subprocess and os module for a while. Now I want to start an interactive C++ program called dumbCalculator from python. This dumbCalculator simply read my input and return its result: when I type 1+2 it returns 3

How can I use my python script to call this dumbCalculator binary? apparently, when dumbCalculator starts, python need to 'give up' its shell.

Any comments?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of these two commands will run an interactive program for you and return to Python when the program ends. They will not necessarily return a value from that program. 'bc' is an interactive calculator for testing. It will let you add numbers and then return to Python when you type 'quit'.

```
>>> os.system("bc")

>>> subprocess.call("bc")
```

Comment: +1, also check out the `python-sh` project if it gets any more complex than this.

Comment: Links are nice.  I think you mean this [python-sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh), but please correct me if this is the wrong one.